# Laravel-chef server Invalid signature for user or client

Tags: php, laravel, chef-infra

Trying to connect to Chef server with [Jenssegers/php-chef](https://github.com/jenssegers/php-chef) package, but it doesn't pass the authorization. Seems to create a signature but throws an error:

```
Exception in Chef.php line 187:
Invalid signature for user or client 'test'
```

This is my config chef file:

```
return [
'server'    => 'https://172.16.0.227:443/organizations/myOrgName',
'client'    => 'test',
'key'       => '../.chef/test.pem',
'version'   => '12.4.1',
'enterprise' => false
];
```

I have tried with enterprise set to be true, but it returns the same error. This are the generated headers:

```
"Accept: application/json"
"Content-Type: application/json"
"X-Chef-Version: 12.4.1"
"X-Ops-Reporting-Protocol-Version: 0.1.0"
"X-Ops-Sign: algorithm=sha1;version=1.0"
"X-Ops-UserId: test"
"X-Ops-Timestamp: 2016-04-05T14:19:35Z"
"X-Ops-Content-Hash: 2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk="
"X-Ops-Authorization-1: o1YdPBVm9uBCz9ZK/b9S6J8L/4z1rH6ep8LmnSqrV1HKK2m5og2o32cv7PUp"
"X-Ops-Authorization-2: 81rk1uTsxy67mOXXuH2T/T4r2nl+WP2pCdpzSUPX6XF8HKSgIMG9TkIzBNcS"
"X-Ops-Authorization-3: ckh5rvj/rtp/XX/VmulOa337cY45I0AudC2MF03LcAPC7sjIekX3NI+xxLe9"
"X-Ops-Authorization-4: 6+lgWndwndql9R/JVwTPIA2VocHt1qFvYrPLRwjr2+x8XE5UGJ3WhRERxEeU"
"X-Ops-Authorization-5: /Z83gjJJsyoFbAw1mWfQJpPbSf2H1Jbit+vd0H5JO28OTVukXLdY5Phk6oQp"
"X-Ops-Authorization-6: yyLpsrvqQeOtZcSBHCKOGigM/HiFO5ZyyDENd6B1Zw=="
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you want `enterprise` to be true, but I don't know if that will fix it. Can you get a debug log with the actual generated authentication headers?

Comment: I have added the generated authentication headers to the question